# Stage management with AWS Mobile hub and AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-mobilehub, aws-amplify, amazon-mobile-hub

I am currently writing a web app and am using AWS Amplify.

I created my API Gateway and my lambdas before using Amplify so I imported my existing API to Mobile Hub.

My API gateway has 2 stages dev and prod.

According to the Amplify documentation here is the code to call my API from my app.

```
API.get(apiName, path, myInit).then(response => {
    // Add your code here
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response)
});
```

apiName is auto generated by Mobile Hub and is always ...amazonaws.com/dev
path will be /items for example

resulting in a call being made to ...amazonaws.com/dev/items

I haven't seen anything in Amplify or AWS documentation to be able to call ...amazonaws.com/prod/items using the Amplify library.

I tried to edit the `mobile-hub-project.yml` and change it from :

```
features:
  cloudlogic: !com.amazonaws.mobilehub.v0.CloudLogic 
    components:
      apiName: !com.amazonaws.mobilehub.v0.API 
        attributes:
          ...
          sdk-generation-stage-name: dev
```

to :

```
features:
  cloudlogic: !com.amazonaws.mobilehub.v0.CloudLogic 
    components:
      apiName: !com.amazonaws.mobilehub.v0.API 
        attributes:
          ...
          sdk-generation-stage-name: prod
```

and push the new configuration but the behaviour is still the same.

Could anyone help me to manage multiple stages using Amplify ?

Answer (score 0):

can you check the file `aws-exports.js` on `aws_cloud_logic_custom` array. there each endpoint has an attribute called `name` which is the one you use with the Amplify. You can edit the `endpoint` by changing to the stage you want to use. By default `aws-exports`uses dev stage.